# MS Updates for MS17-010

Tags: updates, microsoft

Anybody know what the KB numbers are for Windows 10 1607 64 bit and 64 bit for 1511?  I am assuming these are them, can someone please verify this for me?
Also, for the Windows 1607 there is a cumulative update and delta update, which one?  MS makes this pretty confusing.

http://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4013198
http://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4013429

Thanks, Bob

Comment: The [main page for MS17-010](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/security/ms17-010.aspx) contains a big table which include all affected OS and the fixes. All the affected Windows 10 builds are also listed there including the KB.  And yes, the KB you've found are the correct ones but there are also KB 3210721 and 3213986 referenced. As for cumulative vs. delta - the first one includes all previous fixes and the delta expects that you have the previous updates already installed.

Comment: Sounds like the KB3210721 and the KB3213986 updates on the right side of the list are replaced by KB4013198 and KB4013429 respectively.  That is what I am getting out of it.  Here is a reddit post I found online, looks accurate.  https://www.reddit.com/r/pcmasterrace/comments/6atu62/psa_massive_ransomware_campaign_wcry_is_currently/